# EF for Application Releases

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

i've a question but a little special one.

I have an application. But the application deployed for 2 different company, 2 different server.

1st Company has v1.1 release,
2nd Company has v1.8 release.

I just want to upgrade version from 1.1 to 1.8 for 1st Company.
But for v1.1, the database objects are missing according to 1.8.
How can i upgrade DB side?
Is EF automatically generate missing object in db?
Please help, I'm stuck:)

Thank you,
Mert